# object rotation with eulerAngles not working properly

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate an object based on the arrow keys but it gets stuck. The left and right keys work perfectly but the up and down keys get stuck at 90 degrees. This is my code:

```
void turnCube()
{
        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            Camera.main.transform.parent.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0,1,0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            Camera.main.transform.parent.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0,-1,0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.UpArrow))
        {
            Camera.main.transform.parent.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(1,0,0);
        }

        if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.DownArrow))
        {
            Camera.main.transform.parent.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(-1,0,0);
        }
}
```

Comment: why are  you not using `Camera.main.transform.eulerAngles += new Vector3(0,1,0);` ? I am not clear what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Unity3D API,

> **Transform.eulerAngles**
>
> Only use this variable to read and set the angles to absolute values.
>   Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360
>   degrees. Use Transform.Rotate instead.

So use [Transform.Rotate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html),

```
if(Input.GetKey (KeyCode.LeftArrow))
{
    Camera.main.transform.Rotate(Vector3.left * Time.deltaTime);
}
```